# ObjectDataSource.SelectMethod equivalent in SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, sqldatasource

In ObjectDataSource we have a method called SelectMethod and TypeName in which we can specify a method to select data from.

But what is the equivalent method in SqlDataSource to speicify a method for data to select from. If there is no such method, how can I specify a method to select data like in ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjEmployees" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetEmployees" TypeName="AllowPaging.GetData">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=NIPUNA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; database=KTD; Trusted_Connection=yes;");
    string commandText = "SELECT * FROM [Emp]";
    public DataSet GetEmployees()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: https://web.archive.org/web/20211010104134/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112206-1.aspx

the SqlDataSource and ObjectDataSource raise their Selecting events immediately before performing the SQL query or invoking the object method to retrieve data. After the data has been retrieved, the Selected events fires. By creating a Selecting event handler, you can examine and massage the parameters used in selecting data;

You can use these event handlers to specify which method is used by the datasource control.

Comment: Thanks for the behind the scene overview and the link. I looking forward to go through the series ASAP....

Answer (score 0):

In SqlDataSource, it's equivalent is [SelectCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand.aspx). You can either provide the Select query and set `SelectCommandType` to `Text`(default) or use a stored procedure and set `SelectCommandType` to `StoredProcedure`

Comment: I know but I want to specify a method as in objectDataSource. (like getEmployee method above) is it possible?

Comment: Well, They are two different DataSource providers. Objects have methods; with databases, you have to use a sql query or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Data Source executes the SQL inline, so there is no equivalent way of calling a method on an object.  You have to use the SeelctCommand to provide the SQL query directly in the UI.

If you are using business components to execute your queries, stick with the ObjectDataSource.

HTH.

Comment: Yes after Googling about the difference between SqlDataSourceand the ObjectDataSource, I think I better move on to ObjectDataSource. Thanks!!